# java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 64 bytes, but had 25

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I am using hbase with phoenix i may have some non-ascii charater in my data but as now they have already in my hbase and when i am trying to query that data from phoenix like:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col5
from "ns:table1" as a
inner join table2 "ns:table2" as b
    on a.col1 = b.col1;
```

but everytime I am running this query on phoenix shell this error is popping out:

```
Error: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 64 bytes, but had 25 (state=22000,code=201)
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 64 bytes, but had 25
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:386)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseRemoteException(ServerUtil.java:131)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerExceptionOrNull(ServerUtil.java:115)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:104)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:538)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:510)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.RoundRobinResultIterator.getIterators(RoundRobinResultIterator.java:176)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.RoundRobinResultIterator.next(RoundRobinResultIterator.java:91)
        at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.DelegateResultIterator.next(DelegateResultIterator.java:44)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.UpsertCompiler$2.execute(UpsertCompiler.java:680)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:305)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:295)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1255)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
```

I thouhgt this may be because of non-ascii character in my data so i tried to assign varchar to each field but still same error. is there any way so that i can get rid of this error or atleast during this query i may ignore this data which is causing error ?

table schema for table1:
'TABLE_CAT','TABLE_SCHEM','TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME','DATA_TYPE','TYPE_NAME','COLUMN_SIZE','BUFFER_LENGTH','DECIMAL_DIGITS','NUM_PREC_RADIX','NULLABLE','REMARKS','COLUMN_DEF','SQL_DATA_TYPE','SQL_DATETIME_SUB','CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH','ORDINAL_POSITION','IS_NULLABLE','SCOPE_CATALOG','SCOPE_SCHEMA','SCOPE_TABLE','SOURCE_DATA_TYPE','IS_AUTOINCREMENT','ARRAY_SIZE','COLUMN_FAMILY','TYPE_ID','VIEW_CONSTANT','MULTI_TENANT','KEY_SEQ'
'','','ns:table1','sno','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','0','','','null','null','null','1','false','','','','null','','null','','12','','','1'
'','','ns:table1','col1','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','2','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table1','col2','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','3','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table1','col3','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','4','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table1','col4','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','5','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table1','col5','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','6','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table1','col6','12','VARCHAR','null','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','7','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'**

table schema for table2:
'TABLE_CAT','TABLE_SCHEM','TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME','DATA_TYPE','TYPE_NAME','COLUMN_SIZE','BUFFER_LENGTH','DECIMAL_DIGITS','NUM_PREC_RADIX','NULLABLE','REMARKS','COLUMN_DEF','SQL_DATA_TYPE','SQL_DATETIME_SUB','CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH','ORDINAL_POSITION','IS_NULLABLE','SCOPE_CATALOG','SCOPE_SCHEMA','SCOPE_TABLE','SOURCE_DATA_TYPE','IS_AUTOINCREMENT','ARRAY_SIZE','COLUMN_FAMILY','TYPE_ID','VIEW_CONSTANT','MULTI_TENANT','KEY_SEQ'
'','','ns:table2','sno','12','VARCHAR','250','null','null','null','0','','','null','null','null','1','false','','','','null','','null','','12','','','1'
'','','ns:table2','col1','12','VARCHAR','250','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','2','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table2','col5','12','VARCHAR','250','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','3','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'
'','','ns:table2','col6','12','VARCHAR','250','null','null','null','1','','','null','null','null','4','true','','','','null','','null','pc','12','','','null'**

Comment: Could you share the table definitions for `ns:table1` and `ns:table2` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have added definition for both tables.

Comment: Your edit has left the question unreadable, but my thinking is that maybe your query is trying to store 64 or more bytes of data into a field which can only hold 25 bytes.  This is why I asked for the table definition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah sorry for bad edit and i just trying to fetch data how this is related to store data ?